# What is the best way to fetch data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### I currently use contentful for data management, so it's not the usual axios/fetch method this time.

I'm using useContext to share the data to my components, and have an useEffect that sets the state with the new data. What is the problem you ask? **The ugly syntax**. When i pass the data in the second rerender i can't access the data immediately, the `data[0][0]` doesn't exist yet, so it throws an error. This results in this disgusting syntax: `<h5>{data ? data[0].sys.contentType.sys.id : ""}</h5>` It might be "fine", and it "works". But it looks absolutely atrocious to me.

App.jsx

```js
const App = () => {
  const contentfulHook = useState(null);

  
  useEffect((e) => {
    client.getEntries().then((res) => contentfulHook[1](res.items));

/*
    OR - same result
    (async () => {
      const data = await client.getEntries().then((res) => res.items);
      contentfulHook[1](await data);
    })();
*/
 //Remove preloader when content is loaded
    setTimeout(() => {
      const preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
      preloader.style.opacity = 0;
      preloader.addEventListener("transitionend", (e) => {
        preloader.remove();
      });
    }, 0);
  }, []);
  console.log(contentfulHook[0]);

  return (
    <contentfulContext.Provider value={contentfulHook}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Global />
        <Pages />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </contentfulContext.Provider>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Can you use array destructuring? That's what's usually used: `const [value, setValue] = contentfulHook`

Comment: I want to pass both the readState and setState in the provider, the syntax is only like that in App.jsx, so i can use both if needed

Comment: Yup, that's why I destructured `contentfulHook` in the example. Is the issue more about always having to check for undefined/null rather than having to index into what useState returns?

Comment: Yes, i find the syntax ugly and unpleasing to the eye. I would like to be able to use the data without having to check conditionally if the data exist

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I understand. This is something that [Suspense for Data fetching](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) would solve. I think [SWR](https://swr.now.sh/) already works with Suspense.

Comment: By the way, check out [CodeReview Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - your question is bang on for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest two things on that matter:

1. Encapsulate that request logic in a custom hook, so you can remove that code from your component.
2. Use `data`, `loading` and `error` pattern (as used by Apollo and probably other libraries).

The result would be something like:

```js
const App = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useRequest();

  return (
    <contentfulContext.Provider value={data}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Global />
        <Pages />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </contentfulContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useRequest = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    client.getEntries()
      .then((res) => setData(res.items))
      .catch((e) => setError(e))
      .finally(() => {
        removePreloader();
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return { data, loading, error };
}

const removePreloader = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
    preloader.style.opacity = 0;
    preloader.addEventListener("transitionend", (e) => {
      preloader.remove();
    });
  }, 0);
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Either way, you still need to check for the data before accessing the `data` attributes when rendering. Even if it is on a top-level condition like:

```js
const App = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useRequest();

  return (
    <contentfulContext.Provider value={data}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Global />
        <Pages />
        {data && <h5>{data[0].sys.contentType}</h5>}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </contentfulContext.Provider>
  );
};
```